# What is the cubic expectation (third-order moment) of a complex gaussian vector (say, E[$aa^{T}a$])?

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, covariance-matrix, conditional-expectation, complex-numbers

Note: [I also posted this question on MATHEMATICS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4453347/what-is-the-cubic-expectation-third-order-moment-of-a-complex-gaussian-vector).

For **a real gaussian vector**, an explicit formula for the cubic expectation can be found in *Matrix Reference Manual* ([search 'Cubic Expectations' in this link for detail](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/expect.html)), i.e.,

say $a$ is a complex gaussian (vector) process with the mean $E[a] = m$ and covariance $Cov[a] = S$, then we have

E[$aa^{T}a$] = E$[a^{T}aa^{T}]^{T}$ = $2Sm + (tr(S)+ m^{T}m)×m$

where $×$ stands for the operation of skew-symmetric matrix ([search 'skew-symmetric matrix' in this link for detail](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/intro.html#Notation)).

**But what about the cubic expectation of complex gaussian vectors?**

In *Matrix Reference Manual*, you can find explicit formulae for even-order moments of complex vectors, but not for odd-order moments. Usually, we talk about zero-mean vectors, therefore the cubic expectation is ignored. However, for conditional expectation, the odd-order moments may not be zero.

**Does anyone know how to find an explicit formula** like the one posted above? Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: Cross posting may not a good idea.

Comment: How is $aa^Ta$ defined in terms of _matrix algebra_? (Forget the expectation for now), just concentrate on the matrix multiplications. Is the end result a row vector? a column vector? a $2\times 2$ matrix?

Answer (score 0):

If you write a = m + x where m is the mean and x has zero mean then you can expand your cubic expression by multiplying it out. All the odd powers of x in your expansion will have zero mean and you can write down expressions for the even powers. Hope this helps.